# Seriam [localstorage] e [html5-localstorage] sinônimas?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags-sinônimas

Pelo que estou entendendo da [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage), o objeto `localStorage` roda dentro de um escopo com origem HTML5.

Então, não sei se estou vendo muita utilidade para [html5-localstorage](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-localstorage) e talvez devesse ser sinonimizada com [localstorage](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localstorage), mas não tenho uma opinião informada. Também nunca fiz esse procedimento, e me parece que tem que ser aqui no meta mesmo em vez do *Sugerir um sinônimo* nas páginas de tag:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/localstorage/synonyms

<sub>PS: me dei conta que escrevi a pergunta sem conferir no SO, mas lá nem existe `html5-localstorage` e acho que estão com [[local-storage]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local-storage) grafado errado.</sub>

Comment: Dentro do meu limitado conhecimento sobre o assunto, são sim.

Comment: Acredito que isso foi uma confusão com o termo HTML5-webstorage (Que inclui o sessionStorage e localStorage)

Comment: E o que acha de como devem ser organizadas as tags, @jeferson?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiz a mescla das duas tags, porque realmente não faz sentido a diferenciação.

Answer (score -2):

A API WebStorage fala de localstorage e não html5-localstorage, logo o que acato como padrão a ser utilizado é  localstorage.